# Updating Table column when inserting value in another column

Tags: sql-server, database

I have an assignment where I'm suppose to make a table update one column by itself when an value is inserted in another column in the same table. I'm not allowed to use triggers.

Got table test1 with columns (col1, col2), and when the value 3, 4 or 5 is inserted in col2 I want to change the value in col1 to 'G' for the same row.

How can I do this without triggers?

I have looked around and don't see how this is possible without an trigger but professor keeps saying it has to be without...

Comment: Use a case expression in your insert?

Comment: I'm no expert in `tsql` but is it possible to use a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017) for this with a case expression?

Comment: Go back to your "assignment". Rows are inserted, not columns. Columns can be set using insert or update statements. So - restate your actual requirements using that terminology. Are you inserting rows that require this logic? Are you updating rows that require this logic? Or both? You said "no triggers" - why?

Comment: Author has too many spelling errors. Kind of careless.

Answer (score 0):

Or a IIF statement. 
insert into test1 (Col1,Col2) Values (iif(@Col2 in (3,4,5),'G',''),@Col2)

Answer (score 0):

You are using some confusing terms here. What do mean exactly by "value is inserted in column"? When we talk SQL, we do not use the word `insert` in terms of "store data", rather than the actual command itself.

So, tell us: Are you trying to `INSERT` a new row, or `UPDATE` an existing one?

If you are `INSERT`ing, then the simple answer as Sean Lange stated is a `CASE` statement, like for example:

```
insert test1(col1,col2)
select case when value_for_col2 in (3,4,5) then 'G' else NULL end,value_for_col2
from some_other_table
```

If you are `UPDATE`ing, then you can do basically the same:

```
update test1
set col2=some_new_value,
col1=case when value_for_col2 in (3,4,5) then 'G' else col2 end
```

which keeps the col1 value intact for col2 values different than 3,4,5.